# How to typecast a void pointer into a string in C?

Tags: c, generics, linked-list, stack, void-pointers

I am writing a program for generic stack using generic Linked List. Basically, each currNd -> data is void* data. So I am using sprintf to actually format the data into my str string variable. But the problem is when currNd is an integer or reals, it would not work. Is there any suggestions to convert double, float, int to string variable so that I can use it in my toString functions?

This is the code for insertion

```
char *name = "Alex";
int id = 23219434;
int age = 24;
double mark = 89.5;
char grade = 'A';

push( stack, name );
push( stack, &id );
push( stack, &age );
push( stack, &mark );
push( stack, &grade );

printf("%s\n", toString(stack)); /* Output is only Alex (some strange symbols) and A */
```

My toString

```
char* toString(LinkedList *list)
{
    char *str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * STR_LENGTH);

    /* Traversal starts from head */
    LinkedListNode *currNd = list -> head;     

    /* Store the string as traversing the linked list */
    while( currNd != NULL )
    {
        /* Format all data to be string */
        sprintf(str, "%s ", (char*)(currNd -> data));
        printf("%s\n", str);
        currNd = currNd -> next; /* Move to the next node */
    }
    return str;
}
```

The output which is readable is only name and grade. Other numerical variables just return some strange symbols. Hope the question is clear, Thank you!

Comment: Post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), like it is your question is virtually unanswerable. And do you mean typecast?

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it

Comment: `23219434` can be too large for a `int`, a `int` is required to be able to hold values up to at least `32768`. Use `long`, `uint_least32_t`, `uint_fast32_t` or `uint32_t`, which may or may not exist, if you want to store an integer with up to 32 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does not make a lot of sense:

```
/* Format all data to be string */
sprintf(str, "%s ", (char*)(currNd -> data)); (1)
printf("%s\n", str);                          (2)
```

Because (1) means that currNd->data is actually a string.
If currNd->data is a string, there is not need to convert it into a temporary (malloced) string.

This line would be enough:

```
printf("%s\n", currNd -> data);
```

We cannot say much about the code, because we don't know about `push` and about `LinkedList`. But I assume that `push` need to do 2 different things. If the parameter is a `string`, it should store it as `string`. If the parameter is an `integer` it should store it as an `integer`.

Therefore, it seems that the function `push` is missing an enum type parameter.

```
push( stack, name, TT_TYPE_STRING ); // will store the string
push( stack, id,  TT_TYPE_INT  );    // will store the integer
push( stack, age, TT_TYPE_INT  );    // will store the integer
```

Regarding the function `toString()` it should check the type of the item. If it is a string, the previous `printf("%s", ...)` should be fine, if it is an integer, you should call `printf(%d", ...)`.

So I expect your data structure to miss an important point:

```
struct ListItem
{
  enum ItemType; /* INT OR String OR Something */
  int IntValue;
  char *StringValue;
};
```

Comment: I see, I have missed out the enum. Thank you